# PHP - Descargar todos los archivos y carpetas del directorio raíz de un servidor FTP

Tags: php, ftp

Necesito crear un script PHP que me permita poder descargar/clonar todos los archivos y carpetas del directorio raíz de mi servidor FTP (el tamaño total es de aproximadamente 5GB, por lo que debe tomarse su tiempo).

¿Cómo puedo realizar esto?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: echale un ojo a este post activo, igual te ayuda a: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/89999/forzar-navegadores-a-descargar-archivos-subidos-al-servidor-con-php#89999

Comment: @GDP entendiste mal, no quiero forzar la descarga.. quiero un script para clonar la carpeta / y todos los archivos/carpetas/directorios de mi servidor FTP. tampoco me ayudo..?

Answer (score 1):

Guarda los nombres de los archivos en una tabla o arreglo, seleccionas la carpeta 
y con un for each repites el procedimiento de descargar aqui te dejo una imagen del codigo que utilice para descargar muchos elementos con vba desde access

[image: descargar todo]